# Validation on Video size? (regular expression?)

Tags: asp.net

In my web application while uploading a  video file i restrict the user to upload up to 10 mb not more than 10 Mb, i write code for this, but can i get regular expression for size of the video, when user upload the video in fileupload control. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
long numBytes = this.FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length;
double dLen = Convert.ToDouble(numBytes / 1000000);
```

dLen will be the size in MB.

Comment: YoNeed   i write like this but is there any validation expression thank you  for response

Comment: if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
   long numBytes = this.FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length;
   double dLen = Convert.ToDouble(numBytes / 1000000);


}

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this in ASP.NET but it's better to check locally with JavaScript *as well* to avoid wasting bandwidth. The file selector `input` box has some file-related properties, such as this one that you can check to see it's under 10MiB before uploading.

```
fileInput.files[0].size;
```

So, your check would be:

```
if (fileInput.files[0].size > 10485760) ...
```

Comment: i write like this but is there any validation expression thank you  for response